# Vote up/down time out issue

Tags: support, down-votes, up-votes, 408-timeout

The issue is with answer [Drupal incorrectly escapes tags in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430791/drupal-incorrectly-escapes-tags-in-javascript/2432658#2432658).

I up-vote the answer about two days ago, I just tried to mark it also ask Accepted.
But accidentally I down-vote the answer. After this I tried up-vote it again and obtain the error message:

Vote is too old to be changed.

How to return my up-vote back?

Answer (score 2):

There is a very limited window to change votes due to many exploits around this.

I edited the post, which enables re-voting.